# List and sets, how to use conditions on values

Tags: python, list, search, set

I have a list, which contains sets. I have been stuck for 6 hours but still couldn't figure out how to pull out values inside the list.

I need to use conditions on these and get a def search going.

The code goes like these:

```
list_a = {1: x, 2: x}
list_b = {1: a, 2: b}
list_c = {1: [q, w, e, r], 2: [a, s, d, f]}
```

I need to extract the values and make a search function.

```
model = {'1':"A123", '2':"9210"}
brand = {'1':"IPhone", '2': "Nokia"}
price = {'1': "4000.00", '2':"200.00"}
feature = {'1':["Wi-fi", "DualSim", "MAC OS"], '2':["Snake","Backlight"]}`


def search():
    lowprice=float(raw_input("Enter lower bound of price: "))
    upperprice= float(raw_input("Enter upper bound of price: "))
    brandfinder=raw_input("Enter brand name: ")
    for key in model: 
        brandholder = str(brand[key])
        priceholder = float(price[key])
        brandholder = str(brand[key])
        modelholder = str(model[key])
        priceholder = str(price[key])

    if priceholder > lowprice:
        if priceholder < upperprice
        print key +". " + brandholder + ", " + modelholder + ", P" + priceholder
        print "Features: " + str(feature[key])
```

I'd have to put a price range and a brand name on input for that def function. I keep on failing to get the right code for it.. its not giving the right output.

Comment: You need to show the code you have tried and describe what happened.

Comment: just to be clear - you have dicts containing lists, not lists containing sets

Comment: If these are *dicts containing lists*, maybe `list_c[1][index]`?

Comment: Or `'q' in c[1]` to check if it is in the list. What are you exactly searching?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest that use `Ctrl+K` instead of `\`code\`` to format block of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to ask what kind of errors you are getting? Because unless what I'm getting it wrong. It seems to be a simple fix.

`lowerprice` is a float and `priceholder` is a string. So when you try to compare which is greater you get an error.

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()
```

Another issue would be the indentation. I assumed you may have entered it wrong in SO. But if you haven't then that is another issue to look at. The indentation I'm referring is for the print below the if statements.

Another thing. When using `<` and `>` to check if a value is between 2 boundary values then you can use them in the same statement as shown.

Also I'd like to ask is why are your floats strings in the price dict if you are converting them anyway? it makes more sense to store them as a float than string.

```
model = {'1':"A123", '2':"9210"}
brand = {'1':"IPhone", '2': "Nokia"}
price = {'1': "4000.00", '2':"200.00"}
feature = {'1':["Wi-fi", "DualSim", "MAC OS"], '2':["Snake","Backlight"]}

def search():
    lowprice=float(input("Enter lower bound of price: "))
    upperprice= float(input("Enter upper bound of price: "))
    brandfinder=input("Enter brand name: ")
    for key in model: 
        brandholder = str(brand[key])
        priceholder = float(price[key])
        brandholder = str(brand[key])
        modelholder = str(model[key])
        priceholder = float(price[key])

        if lowprice < priceholder < upperprice:
            print key +". " + brandholder + ", " + modelholder + ", P" + str(priceholder)
            print "Features: " + str(feature[key])

#Input
Enter lower bound of price: 400
Enter upper bound of price: 5000
Enter brand name: IPhone
#Output
1. IPhone, A123, P4000.0
Features: ['Wi-fi', 'DualSim', 'MAC OS']
```

Comment: I think I had too much unnecessary codes. Thanks for this.

Comment: Your welcome. I left some of the stuff I mentioned like converting to str when it already is in the answer in case you had some reason.